# Macro reader not running properly

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to do the funciton of search and replace based on styles of document. If I do manually it works fine but when I execute the same through macro am not getting the expected result.
I have pasted the macro below.

```
Sub Macro7()    
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("H1")
    With Selection.Find.ParagraphFormat
        With .Shading
            .Texture = wdTextureNone
            .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorBlack
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlack
        End With
        .Borders.Shadow = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "section{^&}"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Just I need to replace the text based on their style.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to replace? In following line you defined no text to replace:

```
 .Text = ""
```

Could you please specify more what is your goal of using this macro.

PS. It is an answer since I cannot write comments yet.